# How to display links based id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, haml, nested-forms

I have a page that displays a title and then a group of links. It looks like this:

[image]

Right now they are displaying all the links that pertain to the entire page and not to the individual titles. I would like for each title to only the links that pertain to it. I am using rails 4, cocoon and haml. Any ideas as to how I might do that?

### essential.rb

```
class Essential < ActiveRecord::Base

    has_many :favorites, :dependent => :destroy
    has_many :catalogs, :dependent => :destroy
    has_many :labels, :dependent => :destroy
    has_many :members,:dependent => :destroy
    has_many :sub_catalogs, through: :catalogs, :dependent => :destroy
    has_many :sub_favorites, through: :favorites, :dependent => :destroy
    has_many :instruments, through: :members, :dependent => :destroy 

    belongs_to :user 

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :favorites, :reject_if => :all_blank, :allow_destroy => true
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :catalogs, :reject_if => :all_blank, :allow_destroy => true
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :labels, :reject_if => :all_blank, :allow_destroy => true
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :members, :reject_if => :all_blank, :allow_destroy => true
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :sub_catalogs, :reject_if => :all_blank, :allow_destroy => true
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :sub_favorites, :reject_if => :all_blank, :allow_destroy => true
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :instruments, :reject_if => :all_blank, :allow_destroy => true

    validates :band_name, :bio, :image, presence: true 

    has_attached_file :image, styles: { medium: "400x400#" }
    validates_attachment_content_type :image, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\z/
end
```

### catalog.rd

```
class Catalog < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :essential
    has_many :sub_catalogs, :dependent => :destroy

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :sub_catalogs, :reject_if => :all_blank, :allow_destroy => true
end
```

### sub_catalog.rb

```
class SubCatalog < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :catalog
end
```

### essentials_controller.rb

```
class EssentialsController < ApplicationController

    before_action :find_essential, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]


    def index
        @essential = Essential.all.order("created_at DESC")
    end

    def new
        @essential = current_user.essentials.build
    end

    def show

    end

    def create
        @essential = current_user.essentials.build(essential_params)

        if @essential.save
            redirect_to @essential, notice: "Successfully created new essential"
        else
            render 'new'
        end
    end

    def edit
    end

    def update
        if @essential.update(essential_params)
            redirect_to @essential
        else
            render 'edit'
        end
    end

    def destroy
        @essential.destroy
        redirect_to root_path, notice: "Successfully deleted Essential"
    end


    private

    def essential_params
        params.require(:essential).permit(:band_name, :bio, :image, :country, :album, 
            favorites_attributes: [:id, :song_title, :url, :url_type, :_destroy, sub_favorites_attributes: [:id, :fav_url, :fav_url_type, :_destroy]],
            members_attributes: [:id, :band_member, :position, :_destroy, instruments_attributes: [:id, :position, :_destroy]], 
            labels_attributes: [:id, :record_label, :_destroy], 
            catalogs_attributes: [:id, :song_name, :_destroy, sub_catalogs_attributes: [:id, :sub_url, :sub_url_type, :_destroy] ])
    end

    def find_essential
        @essential = Essential.find(params[:id])
    end
end
```

### show.html.haml

```
.main_content
    #essential_top.row
        .col-md-4
            = image_tag @essential.image.url(:medium), class: "essential_image"
        .col-md-8
            #essential_info
                %h1= @essential.band_name
                %p.bio= @essential.bio


    .row
        .col-md-6
            #favorites
                %h2 Favorites
                %table
                    - @essential.favorites.each do |favorite|
                        %tr
                            %td= favorite.song_title
                            - @essential.sub_favorites.each do |sub_favorite|
                                %td= link_to sub_favorite.fav_url_type, "https://www.#{sub_favorite.fav_url}"

        .col-md-6
            #catalogs
                %h2 Catalogs
                %table
                    - @essential.catalogs.each do |catalog|
                        %tr
                            %td= "#{catalog.song_name} |"
                            - @essential.sub_catalogs.each do |sub_catalog|
                                %td= link_to sub_catalog.sub_url_type, "https://www.#{sub_catalog.sub_url}"
    .row
        .col-md-6
            #labels
                %h2 Record Label(s)
                %table
                    - @essential.labels.each do |label|
                        %tr
                            %td= label.record_label

        .col-md-6
            #members
                %h2 Members
                %table
                    - @essential.members.each do |member|
                        %tr
                            %td= member.band_member
                            - @essential.instruments.each do |instrument|
                                %td= instrument.position



        .col-md-12
            = link_to "Back", root_path, class: "btn btn-secondary"
            - if user_signed_in?
                = link_to "Edit", edit_essential_path, class: "btn btn-secondary"
                = link_to "Delete", essential_path, method: :delete, data: {confirm: "Are you sure?" }, class: "btn btn-secondary"
```

### form.html.haml

```
= simple_form_for @essential,  html: { multipart: true } do |f|
    - if @essential.errors.any?
        #errors
            %p
                = @essential.errors.count
                Prevented this essential from saving
            %ul
                - @essential.errors.full_message.each do |msg|
                    %li = msg
    .panel-body
        = f.input :band_name,  placeholder: "Band Name", label: false, input_html: { class: 'form-control form-inline'}
        = f.input :bio, placeholder: "Bio", label: false,  input_html: { class: 'form-control'}
        = f.input :image,  placeholder: "Image", label: false, input_html: { class: 'form-control'}
        = f.input :country, collection: ["England", "United States", "Ireland", "Germany", "France", "Finalnd", "Sweden", "Wales", "Scotland", "Denmark", "Iceland", "Spain", "Italy"], input_html: { class: "form-control form-input" }
        = f.input :album, collection: 1..25, input_html: { class: "form-control" }


        .row
            .col-md-6
                %h3 Favorites
                #favorites
                    = f.simple_fields_for :favorites do |favorite|
                        = render 'favorite_fields', f: favorite
                    .links
                    = link_to_add_association 'Add Favorite', f, :favorites, class: 'btn btn-secondary add-button'

            .col-md-6
                %h3 Catalog
                #catalogs
                    = f.simple_fields_for :catalogs do |catalog|
                        = render 'catalog_fields', f: catalog
                    .links
                    = link_to_add_association 'Add Catalog', f, :catalogs, class: 'btn btn-secondary add-button'
        .row
            .col-md-6
                %h3 Record Label(s)
                #labels
                    = f.simple_fields_for :labels do |label|
                        = render 'label_fields', f: label
                    .links
                    = link_to_add_association 'Add Record Label', f, :labels, class: 'btn btn-secondary add-button'
            .col-md-6
                %h3 Band Members
                #members
                    = f.simple_fields_for :members do |member|
                        = render 'member_fields', f: member
                    .links
                    = link_to_add_association 'Add Band Member', f, :members, class: 'btn btn-secondary add-button'






    = f.button :submit, class: 'btn btn-primary'
```

Comment: I like it when I get some info but this is way to much, I am not sure where to start looking, Do we really need to have the form here?

Comment: What do you mean by "displaying all the links that pertain to the entire page and not to the individual titles"

Comment: @MZaragoza I added the form thinking it would help readers understand the nesting of the forms.

Comment: @p4sh4 As for what the title means, each title such as jamming in the above screenshot, has certain links that pertain to it. In the above picture jamming is only supposed to have apple music and soundcloud and the beach is only supposed to have google play and spotify but instead the loops through all the links.

Comment: You're going to need to explain what some of these columns mean, and whether any of them are connected to the song links. I'm assuming things I see here like Catalogs are completely unrelated, so assuming it is, you're going to need to create a new table to keep track of the song links. Otherwise how would the page know which links are valid and which aren't?

Comment: @RaynorKuang if you look at the above models, sub_catalogs( the links and title) are related to catalogs which are related essentials. I have also attached the form to help with understanding the nesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your view file, look at the catalogs section and change it to

```
%h2 Catalogs
%table
  - @essential.catalogs.each do |catalog|
    %tr
      %td= "#{catalog.song_name} |"
      - catalog.sub_catalogs.each do |sub_catalog|
        %td= link_to sub_catalog.sub_url_type, "https://www.#{sub_catalog.sub_url}"
```

change `@essential` to the local variable `catalog`.

Comment: Thanks, does that only work because the sub_catalog loop is nested within the catalog loop?

Comment: yep that's exactly it.  before, you had `@essential.sub_catalogs` which loads all the `sub_catalogs` of all `catalogs` of `@essential` because of the `has_many` through relationship.